# PYQT resources, frozen programs

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer, cx-freeze

Issue/question with PyQT / resources / cx_freeze on Windows:

I'm using QT's resource system to set an application icon. (Goes in the top left corner of the Window for Windows programs) I created the resource in Designer, then used pyrcc4 to create a rc.py file. It works properly on my uncompiled program, but fails to show  (Shows the generic windows program icon instead) when compiling the script with cx_freeze. Note that I am not referring to the icon you click to launch the program - that's not handled by QT, and works properly. Any ideas?  This is my setup.py.

```
from sys import platform
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import module_locator

_dir = module_locator.module_path()

base = None
if platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "Plates",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Downloads approach plates",
    executables = [Executable(_dir + '\\plates.pyw',
    base = base, icon = _dir + '\\icon.ico')],
    )
```

I get no errors when building the program. My rc file does exist (as a compiled python file) in library.zip.

Comment: Qt needs plugins to display some image formats. Look for a folder called 'imageformats' and copy it into your application directory (next to the exe).

Comment: I'd mark this as the solution if you posted as an answer. Thank you. The image folder was (Windows) in Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins. Copying this to my app's directory as you described worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

Qt needs plugins to display some image formats. Look for a folder called 'imageformats' and copy it into your application directory (next to the exe).

The next version of cx_Freeze should find and copy imageformats automatically when you use QtGui.